# Windows 10 Core IoT Insider Preview 10.0.14279.1000 Bluetooth support

Tags: bluetooth, windows-iot, pi-3

I just installed Windows 10 Core IoT Insider Preview 10.0.14279.1000 on a Raspberry PI 3 and I'm a bit disappointed to see that there is no support for the on-board Wifi or Bluetooth...

Later, I read this: http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/WhatsNew.htm, where is stated under "coming soon": Onboard WiFi & Bluetooth.

There is someone who really knows when these will be added? I really don't want to go back to Raspbian because there I had everything what I need.

Thank you very much.
Evdin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Windows 10 IoT Core for Raspberry Pi 3**:

1. [Windows 10 IoT Core (Insider Preview)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsiot) - Build 14376 (Free - 32 bits)

   - Support on-board WiFi, and on-board Bluetooth.
2. [Windows 10 IoT Core Pro](https://www.windowsforiotdevices.com/distributor/index) - (Not Free - 64 bits)

   - Support all features.